# ActionMailer Observer: pass extra attributes possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have an ActionMailer Observer that gets triggered on each email and writes some information to a log database table to keep track of who sends emails. I want to add some metadata to this like logged in user, type of email, etc.

```
class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    if message.header[:client_id]
      EmailLog.create!(:client_id => message.header[:client_id].to_s,
                       :to => message.to ? message.to.join(',') : nil,
                       :cc => message.cc ? message.cc.join(',') : nil,
                       :bcc => message.bcc ? message.bcc.join(',') : nil,
                       :subject => message.subject.to_s,
                       :content => message.multipart? ? message.text_part.body.decoded : message.body.decoded,
                       :reference_type => message.header[:reference_type].to_s,
                       :reference => message.header[:reference].to_s,
                       :user_id => message.header[:user_id].to_s)
    end
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)
```

All this information is available the moment the mail is created.

I currently pass this data via the `message.header`, but then **the values show up in the actual email that is delivered**

Is there a better way to pass information from the ActionMailers to the Observers while preventing this data from actually being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail), there isn't a lot you can do with meta data on the `Mail` object besides the headers.

One approach I considered was persisting the `message_id` along with user details, etc and then retrieving it again in the observer and perform logging after that.

Another I was toying with was to set the message id myself and load it with the user id, etc but that was much the same as setting headers.

Possibly, you could set the header then unset it again in an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating new key-value pair inside `mail` method in the specific mailer class itself.
Example:

```
class UserMailer
  .....
  mail(to: email, subject: 'Your subject', user_id: user.id, client_id: client.id)
end
```

I tried this and it worked. But it appends extra key-values to the response header.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your client (and other objects) as an instance variable on the message object in a `after_action` callback, like this:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  after_action :attach_data

  def attach_data
    self.message.instance_variable_set(:@client, @client)
    self.message.class.send(:attr_reader, :user)
    # ... and more if you'd like
  end
end
```

Then you can access the objects in your mail observer:

```
class EmailDeliveryObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    client = message.client
    EmailLog.create!(:client => client...
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a callback on the mailer itself?

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  after_action :log_email!

  ...

  private

  def log_email!
    EmailLog.create! # should be able to access instance variables from your mailer method here to reference what you need
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That might be a solution to the OP (it was not specified what should happen on errors). But this example might log the email even though it is never sent.  :after_action is called after the mail object was created, but before it is actually sent. The Action Mailer Basics documentation uses this example: `after_action :prevent_delivery_to_guests`.